# using express with bodyParser.json()

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I'm trying to make a post request with ('request') to an express server and can't seem to get req.body:

```
var app = express();
app.use( bodyParser.json() );
app.post( '/push', function(req, res){
  console.log('body', req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200).end();
} );
app.use( handle404 );
```

and making the request:

```
var request = require('request');
request.post(serverURL + '/push', data, function(err, res, body){
      if(err){
        throw err;
      }
      assert.ok(res.statusCode, 404);
      done();
    });
```

req.body logs undefined, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to parse JSON, you need to make sure you're posting JSON. With "request", one straight forward way to do that is by having a `json` property with the content you want to post:

```
request.post(serverURL + '/push', {json: data}, function(err, res, body){
  // process result
});
```

***Note:*** You could use [request-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-json) that always uses JSON to transport request body.